# Could not find the boost lib in the cross-compile environment

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, boost

I was running the configure in the corss-compile env.(in the env, some command will be replaced ex. Gcc to mipsel-openwrt-linux-gcc  ld to mipsel-openwrt-linux-ld…etc)

```
checking for boostlib >= 1.36  no
```

My boost was building by bjam set the gcc to mips g++
I put the so files to /usr/mips/boost/lib  and the include files to /usr/mips/boost/include.

```
export BOOST_ROOT BOOST_INCLUDE BOOST_LIB  to that 
echo $BOOST_ROOT return a correct path
```

But configure fail either..
I tried ldconfig ,  add the path to the ld.so.conf…
All of these don’t work…

Comment: Advise run you `configure` with `strace -f` and find out where it search boost

Comment: @user1034749 I use strace -f ,but the information it returns it's too difficult for me..I can't understand it.

Comment: just `grep` the result with `grep open | grep boost`